# Rails 3 "No implicit conversion of Symbol into String" using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am receiving an error in development that says:

> TypeError in PinsController (no implicit conversion of Symbol into
>   String): app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:55:in `pin_params'
>   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:21:in`create'

Here is the relevant code from the pin_controller.rb file (note the line in question is line 21 & 54 below)

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
      if @pin.save
        redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
      else
        render action: "new"
      end
  end

  def update
      if @pin.update_attributes(pin_params)
        redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
      else
        render action: "edit"
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.where(id: params[:id]).first
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

I receive this error message when i try to upload an image with paperclip

The params for the request can be found below:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"IrpaPeq4QumTqHYJ1Aq5K3ThLtOyxk/wnxAK4aqJ3H4=",
 "pin"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8c2541bed8 @original_filename="url.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pin[image]\"; filename=\"url.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/bx/z9z06xz54n168tjyyzfm15580000gp/T/RackMultipart20131113-7536-45bhws>>,
 "description"=>"Meow."},
 "commit"=>"Create Pin"}
```

I have included a stack track below as well for everyones reference:

```
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:55:in `pin_params'
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:21:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__1990095296606139361__process_action__4259560217300663073__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2870100640610547083__call__2066122351646789695__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Finally the full codebase is available at: https://github.com/tonytrack/pinteresting

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your configuration for paperclip? I can't find it under config/

Comment: I didn't think I needed one. It doesn't mention anything about configuration in the paperclip installation notes. What do I need to do?